# How to pass cards to another player and so on. Say P1 draws 4 of clubs, how do I pass to P2

Tags: python, card

I'm assuming I would want to put it under the Player class where I've started, but no matter what I've done I don't understand how to go about it. I'd prefer to be pointed in the right direction as opposed to just giving me code.

```py
import random

class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, suit, val):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = val

    def show(self):
        print("{} of {}".format(self.value, self.suit))

class Deck(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        self.build()
#suits of the cards
    def build(self):
        for s in ["Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts"]:
            for v in range(1, 14):
                self.cards.append(Card(s, v))

    def show(self):
        for c in self.cards:
            c.show()

#shuffle the deck
    def shuffle(self):
        for i in range(len(self.cards)-1, 0, -1):
            r = random.randint(0, i)
            self.cards[i], self.cards[r] = self.cards[r], self.cards[i]

    def draw(self):
        return self.cards.pop()

class Player(object):

    def __init__(self):
       self.hand = []

#draw cards
    def draw(self, deck):
        self.hand.append(deck.draw())
        return self

#show the cards in the players hand
    def showHand(self):
        for card in self.hand:
            card.show()

#Pass card to next player
    def passCard(self):
        self.hand.pop()


deck = Deck()
deck.shuffle()

bob = Player()
bob.draw(deck).draw(deck).draw(deck).draw(deck)
bob.showHand()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have two methods in the player class:

```
# In Python, prefer snake_case over camelCase
def give_card(self, index):
    return self.hand.pop(index)

def take_card(self, card):
    self.hand.append(card)
```

And then anytime you want to pass one card from one player to another, you would do something like:

```
player_2.take_card(player_1.give_card(0))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, once I read the solution, I realized it was right in front of my face the whole time.